# Formula for adding velocities in opposed motion at relativistic speeds from the perspective of a stationary observer

Tags: general-relativity, velocity

I'm confused by the formula =(+′)/(1+′/^2) whenever I apply it to a specific thought experiment.

I have a third party, stationary observer, who observers to collinear objects moving towards each other, each travelling at .51c. Therefore, the stationary observer should plug in .51c and -.51c to the formula above to find the objects' relative velocities. But this works out to 0, because [.51c + (-.51c)]/(anything) is the same as 0/anything. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) says that "For collinear motions, the speed of the object (e.g. a cannonball fired horizontally out to sea) as measured from the ship would be measured by someone standing on the shore and watching the whole scene through a telescope as" and then gives this formula. So this formula clearly works for objects travelling in the same direction, ie the canonbal is fired from the ship, but is seems to give the wrong velocities for objects moving in opposite directions, towards or away from each other.

A suggested question came up while I was writing this [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245491/special-relativity-and-composition-law-for-velocities-with-respect-to-an-observe). According to the answer there, the values plugged in should both be positive .51c, and this works out to (1.02c)/(1+(.51c)^2)). Is the problem with my understanding just that we always need the absolute value for velocities in this case? That doesn't seem right, since this would imply that canonballs fired from the bow and stern of a ship should have the same velocities relative to the observer.

What I'm also struggling to work out is whether this formula gives the velocity of one moving object relative to the other, or of one of the moving objects relative to the observer. Different sources are unclear and seem to contradict each other.

I have seen there are a lot of historical questions about this, but none of those helped me understand the question more clearly. I am just more lost, so I'm hoping this is not closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are just reading the formula wrong.

In the following, I follow the wikipedia page's conventions religiously.

The observer in the middle sees the left object moving rightwards with velocity $u^\prime=+.51c$ and the man on the right moving leftwards, i.e. with rightwards velocity $v^\prime=-v=-.51c$

The man on the right sees the observer in the middle move with rightwards velocity $+v=+.51c$. Finally, the formula can be applied to find that the man on the right sees that the left object is moving at $$u=\frac{v+u^\prime}{1+vu^\prime/c^2}=\frac{+.51c+.51c}{1+.51^2}\approx+.81c$$
with the important relationship that $0\leqslant u^\prime\leqslant u\leqslant c$ as expected.

Your problem is the standard beginner's misreading: you *must* transform velocities between frames of reference to use this formula, and so you need to make sure you have the quantities in the correct frames of references considered correctly. The man on the right measures unprimed quantities. The observer in the middle measures primed quantities. You have to be extremely clear about these things.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you need 3 frames. Usually I like primed and whatnot, but I'll go with 1, 2 and 3, in that order, spatially.

The formula says:

$$ v_{3, 1} = \frac{v_{2, 1} + v_{3,2}}{1 + \frac{v_{2, 1} + v_{3,2}}{c^2}}\approx 0.81c$$

where $v_{k, j}$ is the velocity of frame $k$ as measured in frame $j$.

You're implementing:
$$ v_{3, 1} \ne \frac{v_{1, 2} + v_{3,2}}{1 + \frac{v_{1, 2} + v_{3,2}}{c^2}}=0$$

where 2 is the "rest" frame.

which doesn't even work in Galilean relativity.